# Computing correlation of vectors by factor label

Tags: r, vector, correlation, factors

I have have two data frames. The first one, `df1`, is a matrix of vectors with labeled columns, like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10), D=rnorm(10), E=rnorm(10))

> df1

        A          B          C           D          E
-0.3200306  0.4370963 -0.9146660  1.03219577  0.5215359
-0.3193144  0.8900656 -1.1720264 -0.42591761  0.1936993
 0.4897262 -1.3970806  0.6054637  0.12487936  1.0149530
 0.3772420  0.8726322  0.3250020 -0.36952560 -0.5447512
-0.6921561 -0.6734468  0.3500812 -0.53373720 -0.6129472
 0.2540649 -1.1911106 -0.3266428  0.14013437  1.0830148
 0.6606825 -0.8942715  1.1099637 -1.52416540 -0.2383048
 1.4767074 -2.1492360  0.2441242 -0.36136344  0.5589114
-0.5338117 -0.2357821  0.7694879 -0.21652356  0.3185631
 3.4215916 -0.3157938  0.8895597  0.09946069 -1.0961730
```

The second data frame, `df2`, contains items that match the `colnames` of `df1`. Example:

```
group <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3")
S1 <- c("A", "D", "E", "C", "B", "D")
S2 <- c("D", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A")
S3 <- c("B", "C", "A", "E", "E", "A")
df2 <- data.frame(group,S1, S2, S3)

> df2

group S1 S2 S3
   1  A  D  B
   1  D  B  C
   2  E  A  A
   2  C  C  E
   3  B  B  E
   3  D  A  A
```

I would like to compute the correlations between the column vectors in `df1` that correspond to the labeled items in `df2`. Specifically, the vectors that match `cor(df2$S1, df2$S2)` and `cor(df2$S1, df2$S3)`.

The output should be something like this:

```
group S1 S2 S3   cor.S1.S2   cor.S1.S3
  1  A  D  B 0.003825055  -0.2817946
  1  D  B  C  -0.2817946  -0.4928023
  2  E  A  A  -0.3856809  -0.3856809
  2  C  C  E           1  -0.3862433
  3  B  B  E           1  -0.3888541
  3  D  A  A 0.003825055 0.003825055
```

I've been trying to resolve this with `cbind[]` but keep running into problems such as the `'x' must be numeric` error with `cor`. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `mapply()`.

```
my.cor <- function(x,y) {
  cor(df1[,x],df1[,y])
}

df2$cor.S1.S2 <- mapply(my.cor,df2$S1,df2$S2)
df2$cor.S2.S3 <- mapply(my.cor,df2$S2,df2$S3)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I noticed that if `d1` is a numeric matrix rather than a data frame it returns a vector of `NA`s -- not a problem in this case though.

Comment: @amurphy I changed the code slightly so that it will work if `df1` is either a data frame or a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would to the get the correlation between the `matrix/data.frame` after subsetting the columns of 'df1' with the columns of 'df2', get the `diag` and assign the output as new column in 'df2'.  Here, I am using `lapply` as we have to do both 'S1 vs S2' and 'S1 vs S3'.

```
df2[c('cor.S1.S2', 'cor.S1.S3')] <-  lapply(c('S2', 'S3'), 
              function(x) diag(cor(df1[, df2[,x]], df1[,df2$S1])))
```